# Hydra hangs after 16 attempts

Tags: brute-force, router, hydra

When I try to brute-force my router's admin page, Hydra is never making more than 16 attempts. After 16 attacks I receive only status updates with less and less tries per minute. Beside that, all processes of these tries are never terminated, as I can still see them running - are they not affected by timeouts?

Am I running Hydra the wrong way, or does my router has some kind of brute-force protection?

```
$ hydra -l user -x3:5:A1 -o pass.txt 192.168.1.1 http-form-post '/index.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:Wrong password'

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2016-06-12 01:41:11

[DATA] max 16 tasks per 1 server, overall 64 tasks, 62192448 login tries (l:1/p:62192448), ~60734 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-post-form on port 80
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAA
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAL
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAP
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAD
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAB
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAF
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAJ
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: user   password: AAH
[STATUS] 16.00 tries/min, 16 tries in 00:01h, 62192432 to do in 64783:47h, 16 active
```

Comment: What's your router model?

Comment: it happens all the time in all kinds of web pages :/